# booting problem along with windows

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu along with Windows OS but, I can't load Windows. The black screen which displays the different OS present is not displaying. Directly Ubuntu is opening. Please help me. The windows files are present in my drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to terminal and run those commands :

```
sudo update-grub
sudo os-prober
```

then reboot.

GRUB should display before booting the OS.

Comment: Or press Shift during the boot process.